# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForRelease'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-performance

I can not find the origin of this error when I compile in release mode. I have the impression that this error appeared without modifying my code (I try to go back with github but I still have this error).

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForRelease'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: The specified path was not found

Gradle with debug flag

22:36:11.767 [ERROR] [FirebasePerformancePlugin] Can't instrument org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/schema/SchemaTypeSystemCompiler.class

**My build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://www.idescout.com/maven/repo/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

**My app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Keys
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Keys
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/*'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-beta2'

    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'

    //Fabric
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }


    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/aa-poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-more-0.1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/aa-poi-3.10-min-0.1.5.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please run gradle with `--debug` and look for something more descriptive.

Comment: @DougStevenson 22:36:11.767 [ERROR] [FirebasePerformancePlugin] Can't instrument org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/schema/SchemaTypeSystemCompiler.class
I get the impression that the problem comes from the Apache library POI that is not compatible with a FirebasePerf. What do you think ?
The complete trace is here : https://pastebin.com/KeP1xwcX

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that sort of error before.  Perf is failing on dealing with that one particular class from the Apache lib.  I'll see if I can get someone here at Firebase to look at it.

Answer (score 7):

After migrating my Android project to Gradle Kotlin DSL I suddenly also receive the `Can't instrument` error by the Firebase Performance Plugin for **any** class of the project, including third-party dependencies. The build eventually aborts with an `OutOfMemoryError`. The error is

```
Can't instrument: ...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.instrumentation.InstrumentationVisitor.<init>(InstrumentationVisitor.java:55)
        ...
```

Looking at the source code of ASM's [ClassVisitor](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/blob/master/asm/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.java#L70) I see that `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown in the constructor when an unhandled api version is passed. [perf-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/perf-plugin/1.2.0) requires version 7.0 of ASM. However when checking the project dependencies with `./gradlew :app:dependencies` I find out that version 6.0 of ASM is used. Obviously some other dependency requires 6.0.

I tried to explicitly overwrite the ASM dependency with

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.ow2.asm") {
            useVersion("7.0")
            because("Version required by Firebase Performance Plugin")
        }
    }
}
```

and in the output of `./gradlew :app:dependencies` I now see that 7.0 is used but I still receive this error :(

**Update:** Downgrading `com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins` from `1.2.0` to `1.1.5` solves the problem for me.

**Update 2:** As of version 2.0.0 of `firebase-plugins` its usage is [deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android#add-perfmon-plugin). The recommended solution is now to use the Performance Monitoring plugin explicitly. <del>After migrating to the new plugin the problem is now solved for me.</del>

**Update 3:** I must withdraw my previous statement. Using the Performance Monitor plugin did fix the build on my local machine but **not** on my Jenkins build server. Also moving the `configurations.all` block mentioned above into the `buildscript` block as commented by Antimonit did not fix the build, although I can see in the output of `./gradlew buildEnvironment` that ASM 7.0 is used for the build.

Comment: I can confirm similar behaviour. On our Jenkins slave we started to get this error and downgrading to 1.1.5 solved it.

Comment: I can also confirm similar issue when updating com.google.firebase:perf-plugin
from 1.1.5 to 1.2.1.

I am also using Kotlin DSL.

Comment: I've experienced similar issues when upgrading to either 1.2.0 or 1.2.1 from 1.1.5. In our case we were not using Kotlin DSL though. We didn't get `OutOfMemoryError` but this started generating log files on our CI which were 350MB in size instead of 150 KB like they used to be!

Comment: Your proposed solution actually works but you might have defined it in a wrong place. Because it is build process that is failing, you want the resolution strategy to be applied for the Gradle process itself, not application on the device. If you place the `configurations.all {}` block into `buildscript {}` of root `build.gradle` file, it will correctly update versions to 7.0.
Also you should be checking for dependencies of buildscript, not `:app` module. Use `gradlew buildEnvironment` to see dependencies of buildscript.

Comment: @Antimonit I moved the `configurations.all` block into `buildscript` and see in the output of `./gradlew buildEnvironment` that ASM 7.0 is used, but the build still fails :(

Answer (score 4):

**Reason**:
When the classpath dependency to `perf-plugin` is defined in the **app-level** `build.gradle` file instead of **project-level** `build.gradle` file, `perf-plugin` (at runtime) get's the **ASM v6** dep even though in it's [POM file](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/perf-plugin/1.2.1) **ASM v7** dep is declared. This triggers the **IllegalArgumentException** in the `perf-plugin` `v1.2.0` and `v1.2.1` because they depend on **ASM v7** however it works fine for `v1.1.5` because it depend on **ASM v6**.

There are a host of posts [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=module+buildscript+dependencies&oq=module+buildscript+dependencies&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.7887j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that explain why the classpath of the top level buildscript is intended to be different from the rest of the project:

---

**Solution:**
This is gradle behavior. A quick solution to this is to define the `perf-plugin` dependency only in the **root-project** `build.gradle` (which is already mentioned in the [public docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android)).

---

**Detailed Explanation:**

#### NO BUG

**root-project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app-level build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'


. . .

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.2'
}
```

---

#### BUG

**root-project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app-level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'


. . .

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.2'
}
```

---

Comparison of `$  ./gradlew clean :buildEnvironment` command on both cases shows that all the references to `org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0` is converted to `org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0` in case of **No Bug** but that didn't happened in the **Bug** case:

#### NO BUG

```
> Task :buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

.  .  .

    +--- com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta04
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0 -> 7.0
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:6.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:6.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0 -> 1.3.31 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04 (*)
|    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
|    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0 (*)
\--- com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.2.1
     \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
```

#### BUG

```
> Task :buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

.  .  .

     +--- com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta04
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:6.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:6.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0 -> 1.3.31 (*)
     |    \--- com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04 (*)
     +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
     \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0 (*)
```

Comment: Sadly, we have plugin defined *only* at root level build.gradle but are still seeing this error.

Comment: I, too, have only defined the plugin at root level and (still) see this error with firebase-plugins 1.2.0.

Comment: @tir38 and Sven Jacobs

Can you share the sample project (over GitHub maybe) so that I can take a look at your configurations and see why this is still happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, because my `buildSrc` directory contained the fork of [gradle android junit jacoco plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin). Once I got rid of it *(actually I replaced source code fork by dependency on original plugin)*, error'd gone. If none of above advice helps you, try to check your `buildSrc` directory.