# Failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForRelease'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

Everyones.

I had some issue when I import firebase perf plugin to my project.
I want to use firebase-perf to trace my networking. 
But when I got that information like this :

```
Can't instrument: ...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.instrumentation.InstrumentationVisitor.<init>(InstrumentationVisitor.java:55)
        ...
```

And I reached same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172123/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithfirebaseperformanceplu)

But the answer did not work for me.
Do any guys have other good question? Please help me.

Comment: Please file an issue with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I did something to solve my issue, I changed firebase-pref plugin version to 1.15.
It's work for me. I think old version use asm 6.0. it's a principal cause